# How can you get the currency symbol from vue-i18n

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I would like to display the currency symbol depending the locale

```
    <p>Every {{ $n(null, 'currency') }} you invest</p>
```

I would like to display

```
    <p>Every $ you invest</p>
```

or

```
    <p>Every £ you invest</p>
```

ect...

and have a way to display the name as well:

```
    <p>Every dollar you invest</p>
```

Comment: save it as dynamic value in vue-i18n

Comment: could you please provide a simple example?

Answer (score 4):

Save currency symbol inside translations messages

VueI18n setup

```
const messages = {
    "en-GB": { currencySymbol: "£" },
    "en-US": { currencySymbol: "$" }
}

export default new VueI18n({
    messages
})
```

component html

```
<p>{{ $t('currencySymbol') }}</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it's not using `vue-i18n` but you could just use the built in [es5 Intl library](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat):

```
let formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'GBP',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2
})
return formatter.format('0')[0] // Would return the first digit which is the currency symbol.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is here:
https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/number.html#custom-formatting

```
const numberFormats = {
  'en-US': {
    currency: {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'USD'
    }
  },
  'ja-JP': {
    currency: {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'JPY',
      currencyDisplay: 'symbol'
    }
  }
}

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  numberFormats
})

new Vue({
  i18n
}).$mount('#app')
```

Template the below:

```
<div id="app">
      <p>{{ $n(100, 'currency') }}</p>
      <p>{{ $n(100, 'currency', 'ja-JP') }}</p>
</div>
```

Output the below:

```
<div id="app">
  <p>$100.00</p>
  <p>￥100</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hacky technique that can be used in your template:

```
    <i18n-n tag="span" :value="0" :format="{ key: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }">
        <template #currency="slotProps">
            <span>{{ slotProps.currency }}</span>
        </template>
        <template #integer="slotProps">
            <span style="display:none">{{ slotProps.integer }}</span>
        </template>
        <template #group="slotProps">
            <span style="display:none">{{ slotProps.group }}</span>
        </template>
        <template #decimal="slotProps">
            <span style="display:none">{{ slotProps.decimal }}</span>
        </template>
        <template #fraction="slotProps">
            <span style="display:none">{{ slotProps.fraction }}</span>
        </template>
    </i18n-n>
```

Documented [here](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/essentials/number.html#custom-formatting).  I believe this answers the OP's question about how to only show the currency symbol using vue-i18n.